# Как правильно добавить объект в массив, который находится в объекте? NodeJS, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Надо добавить в массив requests, который находиться в объекте friends объект request, но я не понимаю как. Как бы не пытался - ругается.

```
request = {
    "name": friend.name,
    "id": friend.id,
    "type": "outbox"
  };
  db.collection('users').updateOne({token: token}, {$push: {friends.requests: request}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Так а на что ругается то?
Я вижу у тебя friends.requests не как стгринга. Попробуй так:

```
db.collection('users').updateOne({token: token}, {$push: {"friends.requests": request}});
```

Вот мой вариант, все работает отлично:

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'

;(async function main(){
    const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    const db = client.db("someDB")
    const collection = db.collection("someCollection")

    await collection.insertOne({token: 123, friends: {requests: []}})

    const request = {
        "name": "some name",
        "id": "some id",
        "type": "outbox"
    };
    await collection.updateOne({token: 123}, {$push: {'friends.requests': request}});

    const results = await collection.find({}).toArray()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))

    client.close()
})()
```